# Copy and paste data from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to copy data from 1 column then paste it into another column in the same table. The data that I want to copy is coming from the saledate_mmddyyyy column which I want to paste it into the SALEDATE column.

I'm getting this error message:

> Msg 271, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The column "saledate_mmddyyyy"
> cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the
> result of a UNION operator.

The code is below

```
UPDATE VISION_SALEHIST4
SET saledate_mmddyyyy = SALEDATE
```

Comment: The error message says: "The column "saledate_mmddyyyy" cannot be modified because... " what is unclear about that?

Comment: Show the table definition.  You can't update a computed column because there's no storage behind it, it's computed live.  You can only update the columns that store data.

Answer (score 0):

`saledate_mmddyyyy`  is a computed column based on `saledate` so you can't updated it directly. Instead of updating `saledate_mmddyyyy`, update the `SALEDATE` column and you will see `saledate_mmddyyyy` update based on the value `SALEDATE` has.

Answer (score 0):

Same Table run  syntax :

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = column2
```

Different Table run  syntax :

```
UPDATE table_name1 
    SET column1 = (
        SELECT column2
        FROM table_name2
        WHERE table_name1.id = table_name2.id
    );
```

Comment: I'v tried the  1st query.  I got this error message. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'saledate_mmddyyyy'.